# Using CMake to link assimp Prebuilt binary

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, assimp

```
├── CMakeLists.txt #root 
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main.cpp
└── ExternalLibrary
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── assimp
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   ├── lib
    │   └── dlls
    └── glad
        └── CMakeLists.txt
```

this my cmake folder structure iam learning cmake but i wanted to know is what an i missing here i get this error when i build

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'assimp.lib'
```

assimp cmakelist contains this

```
project(assimp)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/assimp.dll"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/assimp.lib"
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

ExternalLibrary cmakelists contain this

```
project(Packages)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)

#glfw
add_subdirectory(glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE glfw) 

#glad
add_subdirectory(glad)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE glad)

#assimp
add_subdirectory(assimp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE assimp)
```

app cmakelist contains this

```
project(App)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    src/main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE
    ./src    
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Packages)
```

I want to try to link this way i know this is not the way but still.
what am I doing wrong here and what is the right way if this isn't.

Comment: ***LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'assimp.lib'*** This error means one or more of the following. 1. The file is not in the path or name that you said, 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit. 3. The file is corrupt.

Comment: In addition to that since you appear to be using `msvc` remember that in most cases you will need separate debug and release libraries with msvc. The Debug configuration is not compatible with release and vise versa. Mixing them can cause UB.

Comment: I double checked the lib file is for release and I have both debug and release both show the same error, could it be this is not the correct way to link the assimp lib if so can you give me through the correct way.

Comment: @drescherjm the files are correct as they work correctly with and alternate method i tried to link prebuilt library.

Comment: It is likely that `assimp`/`Package` target is not visible by `App`. Make an alias target like `assimp::assimp` and try to link that.

Comment: Look at the actual linker settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm i think there is something wrong with the structure iam using to bind the prebuilt binary as getting the cmake source code for assimp from git works and links fine, using `find package` and `add_custom_command` to copy the .dll also works in linking the lib and .dll but using this method doesn't, i have provided all the method i used to link it with folder structure can you please show me the proper way to link the folder packages/assimp to the main/src i would really appreciate it thank you.

Comment: @Osyotr thanks for the reply but I am not familiar with making making alias as i would say I am not that much well versed in cmake, could you shown e how could this be done using the structure above. Thank you.